# rotate bone around 3D cursor in pose mode

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I would like to pose my armature using the 3D cursor as pivot point. However, the bone rotates around its own center, even when I set its origin to 3D cursor. I also tried parenting this bone to another bone that I put in the rotation center. However, my bone of interest steadfastly rotates only around its own geometrical center.

How do I get it to rotate around the 3D cursor?

Edit: It is actually a chain of B-bones. It works for the bone that is highest up in the hierarchy, but not for the rest of them.

Comment: you can't use the 3D cursor as a pivot of any bone in Pose mode. Maybe show some screenshots of what you want to do to find another way around.

Comment: I disagree with @moonboots here. It is totally possible to rotate bones around 3D cursor in pose mode. The bone you need to rotate that way must be free of constraints that would prevent it though, like f.ex. being a connected child of another bone.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant you can move around the 3D cursor in Pose mode, but once you begin to animate it won't rotate around as it won't take it into account anymore.

Comment: Yes, all these bones are children of other bones. So I suppose I will have to adjust the location along with the rotation?